# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException when initializing context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm getting an exception when starting my project with the `mvn exec:java` command

**Trace:**

```
2015-08-11 16:57:58 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:60 - Creating bean connectionFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.phistory.app.jetty.JettyInitializer.startJetty(JettyInitializer.java:41)
    at com.phistory.app.Main.main(Main.java:13)
2015-08-11 16:57:58 ERROR ContextLoader:358 - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.phistory.app.jetty.JettyInitializer.startJetty(JettyInitializer.java:41)
    at com.phistory.app.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

**- Jars in my classpath:**

```
    mvn dependency:tree
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO]      ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building XXXXXX 1.0.61
    [INFO]  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ XXXXXX -
    --
    [INFO] XXXXXX:war:1.0.61
    [INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0:provided
    [INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:javadoc:7.0:compile
    [INFO] +- com.the-carpedia:the-carpedia-data:jar:1.2.11:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:javadoc:3.1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.10.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.10.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec: jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:javadoc:1.0.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-engine:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:4.10.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:4.10.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-facet:jar:4.10.4:compile
    [INFO] |  |        \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:4.10.4:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:jar:javadoc:5.3.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.1.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:javadoc:5.2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:javadoc:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:javadoc:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:javadoc:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.3:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:javadoc:2.1:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:javadoc:1.7.10:compile
    [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
    [INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:javadoc:2.6.0:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:javadoc:4.2.0.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:runtime
    [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE:runtime
    [INFO] +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.23:compile
    [INFO] +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:javadoc:2.3.23:compile
    [INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:runtime
    [INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.36:runtime
    [INFO] +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:provided
    [INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:javadoc:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:javadoc:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:javadoc:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.3.2.v20150730:compile
    [INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.12:compile
    [INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
    [INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:javadoc:1.7.12:compile
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.317 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-11T17:01:19+02:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 17M/222M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>XXXX</groupId>
<artifactId>XXXXX</artifactId>
<version>1.0.61</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>XXXX</name>   
<inceptionYear>2014</inceptionYear> 

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    <maven.war.plugin.version>2.3</maven.war.plugin.version>
    <maven.clean.plugin.version>2.5</maven.clean.plugin.version>        

    <javax.ee.version>7.0</javax.ee.version>
    <com.thecarpedia.data.version>1.2.11</com.thecarpedia.data.version>
    <org.springframework.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.freemarker.version>2.3.23</org.freemarker.version>     
    <org.eclipse.jetty.version>9.3.2.v20150730</org.eclipse.jetty.version>
    <org.slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.12</org.slf4j-log4j12.version>
    <commons.collection.version>3.2.1</commons.collection.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.36</mysql.connector.version>   
    <jboss-logging.version>3.3.0.Final</jboss-logging.version>  
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                <target>${java.source.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*-javadoc.jar</packagingExcludes>
                <warName>ROOT</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.clean.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>deployments</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.war</include>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.ee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.ee.version}</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.the-carpedia</groupId>
        <artifactId>the-carpedia-data</artifactId>
        <version>${com.thecarpedia.data.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${org.freemarker.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${org.freemarker.version}</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.collection.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss-logging.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${org.eclipse.jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${org.eclipse.jetty.version}</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${org.eclipse.jetty.version}</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>${org.eclipse.jetty.version}</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-log4j12.version}</version>
        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As you can see I have the `org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE` jar in my classpath. This project had been working fine until recently, but I don't know what changes I must have made introduced this error.

I have tried running it on Jetty and Wildfly 8.2, with the same output.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
I've detected I had an issue with my Database beans @Configuration, I had a circular reference like so:

```
    2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:60 - Creating bean connectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:74 - Creating bean poolableConnectionFactory
2015-08-15 18:50:07 INFO  DatabaseBeansConfig:88 - Creating bean objectPool
```

This was happening until it threw the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

Comment: could you post your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I wonder why you ended up getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` as opposed to a `StackOverflowException`, I would think the the circular calls would fill up the stack and the latter would happen...

Comment: Sorry I missed this answer. You're right I would have expected such effect too

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the `spring-beans:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE` Jar to your IDE `build path`.

In `Eclipse` go to:
Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > User Libraries.

Comment: How about adding the jar to the Classpath via: Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables.

Comment: nothing, I've completely removed the spring-beans jar from the mven dependencies list and added in it in the classpath like you comment, but still the same issue

Comment: You tried it also with the dependency in the pom.xml? Are you running maven inside of eclipse or a command prompt? What is the maven command you are using?

Comment: Yes I've tried excluding the spring-beans jar from all other jars that include it, like so: 

`<exclusions>
 <exclusion>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
 </exclusion>
 </exclusions>` 

and include the dependency on its own, I've tried mixing Spring versions, I've tried different scopes for the dependency.

I've tried running from eclipse and through the maven commands (mvn clean install and mvn exec).

I've pretty much tried every possibility that has occurred to me, and always the damn same error at the same point when initializing the context

Comment: Where is the class you are going to run? I don't see you defining the start location of your application anywhere with a `main` method.

Comment: it's called Main, I haven't put the entire command, but I do when I run it, I can see the context starting like in eclipse, until it fails at the same point.

I've also run    `mvn eclipse:clean` just in case, same issue.

it's beyond my understanding really, I can see the spring-beans jar! and I've been running this project no problem for a long time, I don't know what I must have changed for it not to work now, how annoying...

Comment: Right-Click on your Maven parent project (containing parent pom), select `Maven` in the pop-up menu, select `Update Project`. Then rebuild your project from scratch, refresh your workspace, and run the project again.

Comment: nothing, same java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException

Answer (score 0):

Change the Spring version to latest in pom.xml like this

```
    version 2.1.3.RELEASE version
```